# Tetris clone in C++ using SDL

Tags: c++, c++14, sdl, tetris

### Overview

Using SDL and my own tiny wrapper library for it, I've written a tetris clone. I would really appreciate it if someone could take a look at it and tell me if something is particularly bad (or particularly good). I aim to make my code expressive, maintainable, with good abstraction levels, all the good stuff. Because the game is a small tetris clone, performance and such wasn't really a big concern. Also, you may notice that I say "matrice" instead of "matrix". Just don't be weirded out by that. :-)

The project has 1008 lines of code overall, and the wrapper library has ~750, but the library is quite intuitive and really it's only mentioned in the file that does drawing logic, and of course in the main file.

### Tetris files:

game_logic.h:

```
#ifndef _GAME_LOGIC_H__
#define _GAME_LOGIC_H__

/*
 * Code for the actual game elements.
 */

#include "matrice.h"
#include "sdl-plus-plus/drawing.h"
#include "sdl-plus-plus/flow.h"
#include "boost/optional/optional.hpp"
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>
#include <array>
#include <cmath>
#include <unordered_map>

#include <iostream>

namespace Game_logic {
using Score = int;

/*
 * Rotation:
 * used with tetrominos to tell weather they should be rotated
 * clockwise or counter-clockwise.
 */
enum class Rotation : bool { Clockwise, Counter_clockwise };

enum class Angle { Zero = 0, Ninety = 90, One_eighty = 180, Two_seventy = 270 };

/*
 * Tetromino_block_offsets:
 * represents all the blocks of a tetromino offset from
 * it's current position, including (0,0)
 */
class Tetromino_block_offsets {
   public:
    using Blocks = std::unordered_map<Angle, Sdl::Point_vector>;

    explicit Tetromino_block_offsets(const Blocks&) noexcept;

    const Sdl::Point_vector& get() const noexcept;
    void rotate(Rotation) noexcept;
    void clear() noexcept;

   private:
    const Blocks* blocks_;  // This is a pointer instead of a reference
                            // so that assignment would be permitted.
                            // It is never null.
    Sdl::Point_vector no_points_{};
    Angle ang_{Angle::Zero};
};

Angle rotate_angle(Angle, Rotation) noexcept;
int first_quadrant(int) noexcept;

/*
 * Tetromino:
 * represents a complete tetromino,
 * including it's position and color.
 */
struct Tetromino {
    Tetromino(const Tetromino&) = default;
    Tetromino(Tetromino&&) = default;

    Tetromino& operator=(const Tetromino&) = default;
    Tetromino& operator=(Tetromino&&) = default;

    Sdl::Point pos_;
    Tetromino_block_offsets block_offsets_;
    SDL_Color color_;
};

/*
 * block_positions:
 * returns the block_positions that a tetrkomino takes up, i.e.,
 * every offset + the tetromino position
 */
Sdl::Point_vector block_positions(const Tetromino&);

using Optional_color = boost::optional<SDL_Color>;

constexpr std::size_t table_width = 8;
constexpr std::size_t table_height = 16;
constexpr std::size_t tetromino_count = 7;

/*
 * Tetromino_table:
 * all the positions taken up by tetromino blocks.
 */
class Tetromino_table {
   public:
    using Matrice = Util::Matrice<Optional_color, table_width, table_height>;
    using Row = Matrice::value_type;

    void insert(const Tetromino&) noexcept;
    /*
     * clear_rows:
     * check which rows are filled and clear them, returning the
     * number of rows cleared.
     */
    int clear_rows() noexcept;
    const Matrice& blocks() const noexcept;

   private:
    void clear_row(Row&) noexcept;
    /*
     * apply_gravity:
     * shifts all blocks down if they have empty
     * lines beneath them.
     */
    void apply_gravity() noexcept;
    void shift_row(std::size_t) noexcept;
    int clear_and_count_rows() noexcept;

    Matrice blocks_{};
};

/*
 * safe_move:
 * moves the tetromino by the given point,
 * making sure it doesn't exit the screen or
 * overlap with the table.
 */
void safe_move(Tetromino&, const Tetromino_table&, Sdl::Point) noexcept;

/*
 * safe_rotate:
 * does the same checking as safe_move, except
 * it rotates the tetromino.
 */
void safe_rotate(Tetromino&, const Tetromino_table&, Rotation) noexcept;

bool filled(const Tetromino_table::Row&) noexcept;
bool empty(const Tetromino_table::Row&) noexcept;

/*
 * touches_table:
 * tells weather a tetromino touches a table
 * depending on the given point parameter.
 *
 * example: touches_table(my_table, my_tetromino, { 0, 1 })
 * checks weather any block of my_tetromino has a block below it
 * in my_table.
 */
bool touches_table(const Tetromino_table&,
                   const Tetromino&,
                   Sdl::Point) noexcept;

/*
 * table_has_point:
 * checks if there's a block in the
 * table taking up the given point.
 */
bool table_has_point(const Tetromino_table&, Sdl::Point) noexcept;

/*
 * table_overlaps_tetromino:
 * check if the tetromino and the table overlap.
 */
bool table_overlaps_tetromino(const Tetromino_table&,
                              const Tetromino&) noexcept;

/*
 * overflown:
 * tells weather the table has been overflown with tetrominos,
 * usually meaning a game-over.
 */
bool overflown(const Tetromino_table&) noexcept;
bool on_screen(Sdl::Point) noexcept;
bool on_screen(const Tetromino&) noexcept;
bool touches_ground(const Tetromino&) noexcept;

enum class Tetromino_type { I, O, T, J, L, S, Z };

/*
 * Tetromino_factory:
 * creates random tetrominos on demand.
 */
class Tetromino_factory {
   public:
    Tetromino_factory();
    Tetromino create(Sdl::Point);

   private:
    const Tetromino_block_offsets::Blocks& random_blocks() const noexcept;
    SDL_Color random_color() const noexcept;
    void two_versions(Tetromino_type);
    void one_version(Tetromino_type);
    void add_block_proto(Tetromino_type, Angle, Sdl::Point_vector) noexcept;

    using Block_protypes =
        std::unordered_map<Tetromino_type, Tetromino_block_offsets::Blocks>;

    Block_protypes block_protos_{};
    std::vector<SDL_Color> color_protos_{Sdl::color_red(), 
                                         Sdl::color_blue(),
                                         Sdl::color_green(), 
                                         Sdl::color_yellow()};
    mutable std::random_device rd_{};
};
}  // End Game_logic

#endif
```

game_logic.cpp:

```
#include "game_logic.h"
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

namespace Game_logic {
namespace {
using Point_vector_iterator = Sdl::Point_vector::const_iterator;

using Predicate_f = std::function<bool(Sdl::Point)>;

using Outer_f = std::function<
    bool(Point_vector_iterator, Point_vector_iterator, Predicate_f)>;

bool apply_to_points(Outer_f outer,
                     const Tetromino& tetromino,
                     Predicate_f inner) {
    auto positions = block_positions(tetromino);

    return outer(positions.cbegin(), positions.cend(), inner);
}

bool any_of_points(const Tetromino& tetromino, Predicate_f f) {
    return apply_to_points(std::any_of<Point_vector_iterator, Predicate_f>,
                           tetromino, f);
}

bool all_of_points(const Tetromino& tetromino, Predicate_f f) {
    return apply_to_points(std::all_of<Point_vector_iterator, Predicate_f>,
                           tetromino, f);
}
}

Tetromino_block_offsets::Tetromino_block_offsets(const Blocks& blocks) noexcept
    : blocks_{&blocks} {}

const Sdl::Point_vector& Tetromino_block_offsets::get() const noexcept {
    return blocks_->at(ang_);
}

void Tetromino_block_offsets::rotate(Rotation rot) noexcept {
    ang_ = rotate_angle(ang_, rot);
}

Angle rotate_angle(Angle ang, Rotation rot) noexcept {
    auto ang_raw = static_cast<int>(ang);
    ang_raw += (rot == Rotation::Clockwise) ? -90 : 90;
    return static_cast<Angle>(first_quadrant(ang_raw));
}

int first_quadrant(int ang) noexcept {
    if (ang == -90) {
        return 270;
    }

    if (ang == 360) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ang;
}

Sdl::Point_vector block_positions(const Tetromino& tetromino) {
    auto result = tetromino.block_offsets_.get();

    for (auto& e : result) {
        e += tetromino.pos_;
    }

    return result;
}

void safe_move(Tetromino& tetromino,
               const Tetromino_table& tbl,
               Sdl::Point move_by) noexcept {
    tetromino.pos_ += move_by;

    if (!on_screen(tetromino) || touches_table(tbl, tetromino, {}))
        tetromino.pos_ -= move_by;
}

void safe_rotate(Tetromino& tetromino,
                 const Tetromino_table& tbl,
                 Rotation rot) noexcept {
    auto new_tetromino = tetromino;
    new_tetromino.block_offsets_.rotate(rot);

    if (on_screen(new_tetromino) &&
        !table_overlaps_tetromino(tbl, new_tetromino)) {
        tetromino = std::move(new_tetromino);
    }
}

void Tetromino_table::insert(const Tetromino& tetromino) noexcept {
    for (const auto& block_pos : block_positions(tetromino)) {
        if (on_screen(block_pos)) {
            Util::at(blocks_, block_pos) = tetromino.color_;
        }
    }
}

int Tetromino_table::clear_rows() noexcept {
    auto rows_cleared = clear_and_count_rows();

    if (rows_cleared > 0)
        apply_gravity();

    return rows_cleared;
}

auto Tetromino_table::blocks() const noexcept -> const Matrice& {
    return blocks_;
}

void Tetromino_table::clear_row(Row& row) noexcept {
    for (auto& block : row) {
        block = boost::none;
    }
}

void Tetromino_table::apply_gravity() noexcept {
    Util::for_each_row(blocks_, [this](auto n, auto& row) {
        if (n == 0 || !empty(row) || empty(Util::row(this->blocks_, n - 1)))
            return;

        this->shift_row(n - 1);
        this->clear_row(Util::row(blocks_, n - 1));
        this->apply_gravity();
    });
}

void Tetromino_table::shift_row(std::size_t n) noexcept {
    Util::row(blocks_, n + 1) = Util::row(blocks_, n);
}

int Tetromino_table::clear_and_count_rows() noexcept {
    int counter = 0;

    Util::for_each_row(blocks_, [this, &counter](auto, auto& row) {
        if (filled(row)) {
            ++counter;
            this->clear_row(row);
        }
    });

    return counter;
}

auto block_exists_lambda() noexcept {
    return [](const auto& block) { return block ? true : false; };
}

bool filled(const Tetromino_table::Row& row) noexcept {
    return std::all_of(row.cbegin(), row.cend(), block_exists_lambda());
}

bool empty(const Tetromino_table::Row& row) noexcept {
    return std::none_of(row.cbegin(), row.cend(), block_exists_lambda());
}

bool touches_table(const Tetromino_table& table,
                   const Tetromino& tetromino,
                   Sdl::Point relative) noexcept {
    return any_of_points(tetromino, [&table, relative](const auto& pos) {
        return table_has_point(table, pos + relative);
    });
}

bool table_has_point(const Tetromino_table& table, Sdl::Point point) noexcept {
    bool found = false;

    Util::for_each(table.blocks(),
                   [point, &found](auto pos, const auto& oc) -> void {
                       if (found || !oc)
                           return;

                       if (pos == point)
                           found = true;
                   });

    return found;
}

bool table_overlaps_tetromino(const Tetromino_table& tbl,
                              const Tetromino& tetromino) noexcept {
    return touches_table(tbl, tetromino, {0, 0});
}

bool overflown(const Tetromino_table& table) noexcept {
    /*
     * Overflow happens if there's a block (or multiple blocks)
     * in the topmost row.
     */
    const auto& top_row = Util::row(table.blocks(), 0);

    return std::any_of(top_row.cbegin(), top_row.cend(),
                       [](const auto& e) { return e ? true : false; });
}

bool on_screen(Sdl::Point point) noexcept {
    /*
     * Casting to an unsigned type is okay here, because we
     * first checked to make sure it's larger than 0.
     */

    return point.x >= 0 && static_cast<std::size_t>(point.x) < table_width;
}

bool on_screen(const Tetromino& tetromino) noexcept {
    return all_of_points(tetromino,
                         [](const auto& pos) { return on_screen(pos); });
}

bool touches_ground(const Tetromino& tetromino) noexcept {
    return any_of_points(
        tetromino, [](const auto& pos) { return pos.y == table_height - 1; });
}

Tetromino_factory::Tetromino_factory() {
    add_block_proto(Tetromino_type::I, Angle::Zero,
                    {{-2, 0}, {-1, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}});

    add_block_proto(Tetromino_type::I, Angle::Ninety,
                    {{0, -2}, {0, -1}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}});

    add_block_proto(Tetromino_type::O, Angle::Zero,
                    {{0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 1}});

    add_block_proto(Tetromino_type::S, Angle::Zero,
                    {{-1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}});

    add_block_proto(Tetromino_type::S, Angle::Ninety,
                    {{0, -1}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}});

    add_block_proto(Tetromino_type::T, Angle::Zero,
                    {{0, 1}, {0, 0}, {-1, 0}, {1, 0}});

    add_block_proto(Tetromino_type::T, Angle::Ninety,
                    {{0, -1}, {-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}});

    add_block_proto(Tetromino_type::T, Angle::One_eighty,
                    {{1, 0}, {0, 0}, {-1, 0}, {0, -1}});

    add_block_proto(Tetromino_type::T, Angle::Two_seventy,
                    {{0, -1}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}});

    add_block_proto(Tetromino_type::Z, Angle::Zero,
                    {{-1, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {-1, 1}});

    add_block_proto(Tetromino_type::Z, Angle::Ninety,
                    {{0, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, -1}});

    add_block_proto(Tetromino_type::J, Angle::Zero,
                    {{-1, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}});

    add_block_proto(Tetromino_type::J, Angle::Ninety,
                    {{0, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, -1}, {1, -1}});

    add_block_proto(Tetromino_type::J, Angle::One_eighty,
                    {{-1, -1}, {0, 0}, {-1, 0}, {1, 0}});

    add_block_proto(Tetromino_type::J, Angle::Two_seventy,
                    {{-1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}, {0, -1}});

    add_block_proto(Tetromino_type::L, Angle::Zero,
                    {{-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}});

    add_block_proto(Tetromino_type::L, Angle::Ninety,
                    {{0, -1}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}});

    add_block_proto(Tetromino_type::L, Angle::One_eighty,
                    {
                        {-1, 0}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, -1},
                    });

    add_block_proto(Tetromino_type::L, Angle::Two_seventy,
                    {{-1, -1}, {0, -1}, {0, 0}, {0, 1}});

    two_versions(Tetromino_type::I);
    one_version(Tetromino_type::O);
    two_versions(Tetromino_type::S);
    two_versions(Tetromino_type::Z);
}

Tetromino Tetromino_factory::create(Sdl::Point pos) {
    return {pos, Tetromino_block_offsets{random_blocks()}, random_color()};
}

const Tetromino_block_offsets::Blocks& Tetromino_factory::random_blocks() const
    noexcept {
    auto max = static_cast<int>(Tetromino_type::S);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist{0, max};

    return block_protos_.at(static_cast<Tetromino_type>(dist(rd_)));
}

SDL_Color Tetromino_factory::random_color() const noexcept {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::size_t> dist{0,
                                                    color_protos_.size() - 1};

    return color_protos_[dist(rd_)];
}

void Tetromino_factory::two_versions(Tetromino_type type) {
    auto& blocks = block_protos_[type];
    blocks[Angle::One_eighty] = blocks[Angle::Zero];
    blocks[Angle::Two_seventy] = blocks[Angle::Ninety];
}

void Tetromino_factory::one_version(Tetromino_type type) {
    auto& blocks = block_protos_[type];
    blocks[Angle::Ninety] = blocks[Angle::One_eighty] =
        blocks[Angle::Two_seventy] = blocks[Angle::Zero];
}

void Tetromino_factory::add_block_proto(Tetromino_type type,
                                        Angle ang,
                                        Sdl::Point_vector points) noexcept {
    block_protos_[type][ang] = std::move(points);
}
} // End Game_logic
```

matrice.h:

```
#ifndef _MATRICE_H__
#define _MATRICE_H__

#include "sdl-plus-plus/drawing.h"
#include <cstddef>
#include <array>
#include <functional>
#include <utility
/*
 * General utilities for dealing with matrices
 */
namespace Util {
template <class T, std::size_t W, std::size_t H>
using Matrice = std::array<std::array<T, W>, H>;

/*
 * Value_type:
 * quality of life alias. Saves me from writing
 * a lot of stuff in some declarations.
 */
template <class T>
using Value_type = typename T::value_type;

/*
 * Pres_value_type:
 * extracts the value type from the given class,
 * except if the given class is const,
 * the value type will be const too
 * (i.e., the constness is preserved).
 */
template <class, bool is_const>
struct Pres_value_type;

template <class From>
struct Pres_value_type<From, true> {
    using Type = const Value_type<From>;
};

template <class From>
struct Pres_value_type<From, false> {
    using Type = Value_type<From>;
};

/*
 * Pres_value_type_t:
 * a nice interface to the
 * Pres_value_type class.
 */
template <class From>
using Pres_value_type_t =
    typename Pres_value_type<From, std::is_const<From>::value>::Type;

/*
 * row:
 * accesses the nth row of the matrice.
 */
template <class M>
auto& row(M& matrice, std::size_t n) {
    return matrice.at(n);
}

/*
 * at:
 * accesses the matrice element at the position pos.
 */
template <class M>
auto& at(M& matrice, Sdl::Point pos) {
    return matrice.at(pos.y).at(pos.x);
}

/*
 * for_each_row:
 * apply f to each row.
 * The std::size_t parameter of f is the row number.
 */
template <class M>
void for_each_row(M& matrice,
                  std::function<void(std::size_t, Pres_value_type_t<M>&)> f) {
    for (std::size_t y = 0; y < matrice.size(); ++y) {
        f(y, row(matrice, y));
    }
}

/*
 * for_each:
 * apply f to each individual matrice element.
 * The Sdl::Point parameter of f is the element position.
 */
template <class M>
void for_each(M& matrice,
              std::function<void(Sdl::Point,
                                 Pres_value_type_t<Pres_value_type_t<M>>&)> f) {
    for_each_row(matrice, [f](auto y, auto& row) {
        for (std::size_t x = 0; x < row.size(); ++x) {
            f({static_cast<int>(x), static_cast<int>(y)}, row[x]);
        }
    });
}
}

#endif
```

visuals.h:

```
#ifndef _VISUALS_H__
#define _VISUALS_H__

#include "game_logic.h"
#include "sdl-plus-plus/drawing.h"
#include <cstddef>

/*
 * Code that has to do with drawing elements.
 */

namespace Visuals {
constexpr auto block_width = 20;
constexpr auto block_height = 20;

constexpr std::size_t window_width = block_width * Game_logic::table_width;
constexpr std::size_t window_height = block_height * Game_logic::table_height;

void draw_block(Sdl::Screen&, Sdl::Point, SDL_Color);
void draw_game_element(Sdl::Screen&, const Game_logic::Tetromino&);
void draw_game_element(Sdl::Screen&, const Game_logic::Tetromino_table&);
}

#endif
```

visuals.cpp:

```
#include "visuals.h"
#include "matrice.h"
#include <iostream>

namespace Visuals {
void draw_block(Sdl::Screen& screen, Sdl::Point pos, SDL_Color color) {
    pos *= Sdl::Point{block_width, block_height};

    screen.add_draw(Sdl::make_rect(pos, block_width, block_height), color,
                    Sdl::Color_filling::Filled);
}

void draw_game_element(Sdl::Screen& screen,
                       const Game_logic::Tetromino& tetromino) {
    for (const auto& t_block_pos : Game_logic::block_positions(tetromino)) {
        draw_block(screen, t_block_pos, tetromino.color_);
    }
}

void draw_game_element(Sdl::Screen& screen,
                       const Game_logic::Tetromino_table& table) {
    Util::for_each(table.blocks(), [&screen](auto pos, const auto& e) {
        if (e)
            draw_block(screen, pos, *e);
    });
}
}
```

game.h:

```
#ifndef _GAME_H__
#define _GAME_H__

#include "game_logic.h"
#include "visuals.h"
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>

/*
 * The game implementation,
 * basically the implementation of the game's
 * main loop. This file combines the game logic
 * and visuals.
 */

namespace Game_logic {
enum class Drop_mode : bool { Normal, Fast };

class Game_timer {
   public:
    explicit Game_timer(std::chrono::milliseconds) noexcept;

    static constexpr std::chrono::milliseconds min() noexcept {
        using namespace std::chrono_literals;
        return 50ms;
    }

    static constexpr std::chrono::milliseconds speed_boost() noexcept {
        using namespace std::chrono_literals;
        return 10ms;
    }

    bool ready() noexcept;
    void set_mode(Drop_mode) noexcept;
    void speed_up() noexcept;

   private:
    std::chrono::milliseconds delay_;
    Sdl::Timer timer_;
};

struct Button_dispatcher_data;

/*
 * Button_dispatcher:
 * a function class used to handle button presses.
 */
class Button_dispatcher {
   public:
    Button_dispatcher();
    void operator()(const SDL_Event&, Button_dispatcher_data) noexcept;

   private:
    using Dispatch_function =
        std::function<void(Button_dispatcher_data) noexcept>;
    using Dispatch_map = std::map<SDL_Scancode, Dispatch_function>;

    void do_dispatch(Dispatch_map&,
                     Button_dispatcher_data,
                     const SDL_Scancode&) noexcept;

    Dispatch_map keydown_dispatch_;
    Dispatch_map keyup_dispatch_;
};

/*
 * Button_dispatcher_data:
 * holds the data that may be modified when the user
 * presses/releases a button, depending on which button it was.
 */
struct Button_dispatcher_data {
    Tetromino& tetromino_;
    const Tetromino_table& tbl_;
    /*
     * This field is const because pressing a button
     * should never modify the table directly
     */
    Game_timer& game_timer_;
};

/*
 * Game:
 * represents the whole game process,
 * where the game advances a frame with
 * each call to frame_advance().
 */
class Game {
   public:
    explicit Game(std::chrono::milliseconds) noexcept;

    void frame_advance(const SDL_Event&);
    void frame_advance(Sdl::Screen&);

   private:
    void check_timer() noexcept;
    void handle_event(const SDL_Event&);
    void insert_tetromino() noexcept;
    void reset() noexcept;
    void check_game_over() noexcept;
    void handle_rows() noexcept;
    Tetromino create_tetromino() noexcept;

    Game_timer timer_;
    Button_dispatcher dispatch_button_{};
    Tetromino_factory t_factory_{};
    Tetromino_table t_table_{};
    Tetromino current_tetromino_{create_tetromino()};
    int score_{0};
    bool game_over_{false};
};
}

#endif
```

game.cpp:

```
#include "game.h"

namespace Game_logic {
Game_timer::Game_timer(std::chrono::milliseconds delay) noexcept
    : delay_{delay},
      timer_{delay} {}

bool Game_timer::ready() noexcept {
    return timer_.ready();
}

void Game_timer::set_mode(Drop_mode mode) noexcept {
    if (mode == Drop_mode::Normal) {
        timer_.set_delay(delay_);
    } else if (mode == Drop_mode::Fast) {
        timer_.set_delay(min());
    }
}

void Game_timer::speed_up() noexcept {
    if (delay_ > min()) {
        delay_ -= speed_boost();
    }
}

Button_dispatcher::Button_dispatcher()
    : keydown_dispatch_{
          {SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT, [](auto dispatcher_data) noexcept {
                                  safe_move(dispatcher_data.tetromino_,
                                            dispatcher_data.tbl_,
                                            {-1, 0});
}
}
, {SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT,
   [](auto dispatcher_data) noexcept {
       safe_move(dispatcher_data.tetromino_, dispatcher_data.tbl_, {1, 0});
}
}
, {SDL_SCANCODE_X,
   [](auto dispatcher_data) noexcept {safe_rotate(dispatcher_data.tetromino_,
                                                  dispatcher_data.tbl_,
                                                  Rotation::Clockwise);
}
}
, {SDL_SCANCODE_Y,
   [](auto dispatcher_data) noexcept {safe_rotate(dispatcher_data.tetromino_,
                                                  dispatcher_data.tbl_,
                                                  Rotation::Counter_clockwise);
}
}
, {
    SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN, [](auto dispatcher_data) noexcept {
        dispatcher_data.game_timer_.set_mode(Drop_mode::Fast);
    }
}
}
, keyup_dispatch_{{SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN,
                   [](auto dispatcher_data) noexcept {
                       dispatcher_data.game_timer_.set_mode(Drop_mode::Normal);
}
}
}
{
    // Making sure that the same button does the same thing
    // on both English and German keyboards.
    keydown_dispatch_[SDL_SCANCODE_Z] = keydown_dispatch_[SDL_SCANCODE_Y];
}

void Button_dispatcher::operator()(
    const SDL_Event& event,
    Button_dispatcher_data dispatcher_data) noexcept {
    if (event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
        do_dispatch(keydown_dispatch_, dispatcher_data,
                    event.key.keysym.scancode);
    } else if (event.type == SDL_KEYUP) {
        do_dispatch(keyup_dispatch_, dispatcher_data,
                    event.key.keysym.scancode);
    }
}

void Button_dispatcher::do_dispatch(Dispatch_map& dm,
                                    Button_dispatcher_data dispatcher_data,
                                    const SDL_Scancode& scancode) noexcept {
    if (dm.count(scancode) == 0)
        return;

    dm[scancode](dispatcher_data);
}

Game::Game(std::chrono::milliseconds delay) noexcept : timer_{delay} {}

void Game::frame_advance(const SDL_Event& event) {
    handle_event(event);
}

void Game::frame_advance(Sdl::Screen& screen) {
    check_timer();
    Visuals::draw_game_element(screen, current_tetromino_);
    Visuals::draw_game_element(screen, t_table_);
}

void Game::check_timer() noexcept {
    if (game_over_)
        return;

    if (!timer_.ready())
        return;

    if (touches_ground(current_tetromino_) ||
        touches_table(t_table_, current_tetromino_, {0, 1})) {
        insert_tetromino();
        handle_rows();
        reset();
        check_game_over();
        return;
    }

    current_tetromino_.pos_ += Sdl::Point{0, 1};
}

void Game::handle_event(const SDL_Event& event) {
    dispatch_button_(event, {current_tetromino_, t_table_, timer_});
}

void Game::insert_tetromino() noexcept {
    t_table_.insert(current_tetromino_);
}

void Game::reset() noexcept {
    current_tetromino_ = create_tetromino();
}

void Game::check_game_over() noexcept {
    if (table_overlaps_tetromino(t_table_, current_tetromino_)) {
        game_over_ = true;

        Sdl::Message_content content{};
        content.title = "Game over!";
        content.text = "Final score: " + std::to_string(score_) + ".\n";

        Sdl::show_message(content, Sdl::Message_box_type::Basic);
    }
}

void Game::handle_rows() noexcept {
    auto cleared_rows = t_table_.clear_rows();
    score_ += cleared_rows;

    for (int _ = 0; _ < cleared_rows; ++_) {
        timer_.speed_up();
    }
}

Tetromino Game::create_tetromino() noexcept {
    return t_factory_.create({table_width / 2, 0});
}
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "game_logic.h"
#include "game.h"
#include "sdl-plus-plus/drawing.h"
#include "sdl-plus-plus/flow.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using namespace Sdl;
    using namespace Game_logic;
    using namespace Visuals;
    using namespace std::literals::chrono_literals;

    Sdl_system_control _{};

    Screen_properties props{};
    props.width = window_width;
    props.height = window_height;
    props.title = "HELP";

    Screen screen{props};

    Game tetris{500ms};

    Event_loop ml{[&screen, &tetris](const auto& event) {
                      if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                          return Event_result::Quit;

                      tetris.frame_advance(event);
                      return Event_result::Continue;
                  },
                  [&screen, &tetris] {
                      tetris.frame_advance(screen);
                      screen.redraw(color_white());
                  }};

    ml.start();
}
```

I really don't think you need to look at the wrapper library (unless you actually want to or care), because as I said, it's quite intuitive. In case you do want to look at it:

### Sdl wrapper library:

resource.h:

```
#ifndef _SDLPP__RESOURCE__HEADER__
#define _SDLPP__RESOURCE__HEADER__

#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
#include <stdexcept>
#include <memory>

namespace Sdl {
class Sdl_exception : public std::exception {
   public:
    const char* what() const noexcept override;
};

class Sdl_system_control {
   public:
    Sdl_system_control(Uint32 = SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    ~Sdl_system_control() noexcept;

    // No copying or moving allowed
    Sdl_system_control(const Sdl_system_control&) = delete;
    Sdl_system_control(Sdl_system_control&&) = delete;
    Sdl_system_control& operator=(const Sdl_system_control&) = delete;
    Sdl_system_control& operator=(Sdl_system_control&&) = delete;
};

struct Window_deleter;
struct Renderer_deleter;
struct Surface_deleter;
struct Texture_deleter;

using Unique_window = std::unique_ptr<SDL_Window, Window_deleter>;
using Unique_renderer = std::unique_ptr<SDL_Renderer, Renderer_deleter>;
using Unique_surface = std::unique_ptr<SDL_Surface, Surface_deleter>;
using Shared_texture = std::shared_ptr<SDL_Texture>;

Shared_texture load_texture(const std::string&, Unique_renderer&);

// Exception checking
template <class T>
void check_pointer(const T&);
void check_function(int);

struct Window_deleter {
    void operator()(SDL_Window*) const noexcept;
};

struct Renderer_deleter {
    void operator()(SDL_Renderer*) const noexcept;
};

struct Surface_deleter {
    void operator()(SDL_Surface*) const noexcept;
};

struct Texture_deleter {
    void operator()(SDL_Texture*) const noexcept;
};

template <class T>
void check_pointer(const T& t_ptr) {
    if (t_ptr == nullptr)
        throw Sdl_exception{};
}
}

#endif
```

resource.cpp:

```
#include "resource.h"

namespace Sdl {
const char* Sdl_exception::what() const noexcept {
    return SDL_GetError();
}

Sdl_system_control::Sdl_system_control(Uint32 flags) {
    if (SDL_Init(flags) != 0)
        throw Sdl_exception{};
}

Sdl_system_control::~Sdl_system_control() noexcept {
    SDL_Quit();
}

Shared_texture load_texture(const std::string& name,
                            Unique_renderer& rend_point_pointerer) {
    auto surface = Unique_surface{SDL_LoadBMP(name.c_str())};
    check_pointer(surface);

    auto result = Shared_texture{
        SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(rend_point_pointerer.get(), surface.get()),
        Texture_deleter{}};

    check_pointer(result);

    return result;
}

void check_function(int function_result) {
    if (function_result != 0)
        throw Sdl_exception{};
}

void Window_deleter::operator()(SDL_Window* wnd_ptr) const noexcept {
    SDL_DestroyWindow(wnd_ptr);
}

void Renderer_deleter::operator()(SDL_Renderer* rdr_ptr) const noexcept {
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(rdr_ptr);
}

void Surface_deleter::operator()(SDL_Surface* surf_ptr) const noexcept {
    SDL_FreeSurface(surf_ptr);
}

void Texture_deleter::operator()(SDL_Texture* txr_ptr) const noexcept {
    SDL_DestroyTexture(txr_ptr);
}
}
```

drawing.h:

```
#ifndef _SDLPP__DRAWING__HEADRER__
#define _SDLPP__DRAWING__HEADRER__

#include "SDL2/SDL.h"
#include "resource.h"
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

namespace Sdl {
struct Point;
struct Canvas;
struct Line;

using Point_vector = std::vector<Point>;

struct Point {  // A 2D point, as simple as they make them
    int x;
    int y;
};  // TODO Maybe this shouldn't be a template...

constexpr bool operator==(Point, Point) noexcept;
constexpr bool operator!=(Point, Point) noexcept;
constexpr Point& operator+=(Point& lhs, Point rhs) noexcept;
constexpr Point& operator-=(Point& lhs, Point rhs) noexcept;
constexpr Point& operator*=(Point& lhs, Point rhs) noexcept;
constexpr Point operator+(Point lhs, Point rhs) noexcept;
constexpr Point operator-(Point lhs, Point rhs) noexcept;
constexpr Point operator*(Point lhs, Point rhs) noexcept;

enum class Message_box_type : Uint32 {
    Basic = 0,
    Error = SDL_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR,
    Warning = SDL_MESSAGEBOX_WARNING,
    Info = SDL_MESSAGEBOX_INFORMATION
};

struct Message_content {
    std::string title{};
    std::string text{};
};

void show_message(const Message_content&, Message_box_type);

constexpr SDL_Color color_red(Uint8 = 255, Uint8 alpha = 255) noexcept;
constexpr SDL_Color color_green(Uint8 = 255, Uint8 alpha = 255) noexcept;
constexpr SDL_Color color_blue(Uint8 = 255, Uint8 alpha = 255) noexcept;
constexpr SDL_Color color_yellow(Uint8 = 255, Uint8 alpha = 255) noexcept;
constexpr SDL_Color color_black(Uint8 alpha = 255) noexcept;
constexpr SDL_Color color_white(Uint8 alpha = 255) noexcept;

SDL_Rect make_rect(Sdl::Point, Sdl::Point) noexcept;
SDL_Rect make_rect(Sdl::Point, int w, int h) noexcept;

struct Screen_properties {  // Properties of a window
    int width{800};
    int height{600};
    Point position{SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED};
    std::string title{};
};

struct Canvas {  // A canvas is what you need in order to draw something
    Canvas() = default;
    explicit Canvas(const Screen_properties&);
    // Creates a canvas based on the given window properties

    Unique_window window{nullptr};
    Unique_renderer renderer{nullptr};
};

struct Angle_rad {  // Angle in radians
    double value{};
};

struct Line {
    Line() = default;
    Line(Point, Angle_rad, int) noexcept;
    Line(Point, Point) noexcept;

    Point from{};
    Point to{};
};

struct Drawable_texture {
    Shared_texture texture{nullptr};
    int width{};
    int height{};
};

class Texture_factory {
   public:
    void add(const std::string&, Unique_renderer&);
    bool exists(const std::string&) const noexcept;
    Drawable_texture get(const std::string&) const noexcept;

   private:
    std::map<std::string, Drawable_texture> m_map{};
};

enum class Color_filling : bool { Filled, None };

class Screen {  // Manipulates a canvas
   public:
    explicit Screen(const Screen_properties&);

    void add_draw(const std::string&, Point);
    void add_draw(Line, SDL_Color);
    void add_draw(SDL_Rect, SDL_Color, Color_filling);

    void redraw(SDL_Color);  // Clear, draw, render present

   private:
    using Snapshot = std::function<void(void)>;

    void set_renderer_color(SDL_Color);

    Canvas m_canvas{};
    Texture_factory m_factory{};
    // Stuff to draw
    std::vector<Snapshot> m_snapshots{};
};

// Basic_point operator definitions

constexpr bool operator==(Point lhs, Point rhs) noexcept {
    return lhs.x == rhs.x && lhs.y == rhs.y;
}

constexpr bool operator!=(Point lhs, Point rhs) noexcept {
    return lhs.x != rhs.x && lhs.y != rhs.y;
}

constexpr Point& operator+=(Point& lhs, Point rhs) noexcept {
    lhs.x += rhs.x;
    lhs.y += rhs.y;

    return lhs;
}

constexpr Point& operator-=(Point& lhs, Point rhs) noexcept {
    lhs.x -= rhs.x;
    lhs.y -= rhs.y;

    return lhs;
}

constexpr Point& operator*=(Point& lhs, Point rhs) noexcept {
    lhs.x *= rhs.x;
    lhs.y *= rhs.y;

    return lhs;
}

constexpr Point operator+(Point lhs, Point rhs) noexcept {
    return {lhs.x + rhs.x, lhs.y + rhs.y};
}

constexpr Point operator-(Point lhs, Point rhs) noexcept {
    return {lhs.x - rhs.x, lhs.y - rhs.y};
}

constexpr Point operator*(Point lhs, Point rhs) noexcept {
    return {lhs.x * rhs.x, lhs.y * rhs.y};
}

constexpr SDL_Color color_red(Uint8 amount, Uint8 alpha) noexcept {
    return {amount, 0, 0, alpha};
}

constexpr SDL_Color color_green(Uint8 amount, Uint8 alpha) noexcept {
    return {0, amount, 0, alpha};
}

constexpr SDL_Color color_blue(Uint8 amount, Uint8 alpha) noexcept {
    return {0, 0, amount, alpha};
}

constexpr SDL_Color color_yellow(Uint8 amount, Uint8 alpha) noexcept {
    return {amount, amount, 0, alpha};
}

constexpr SDL_Color color_black(Uint8 alpha) noexcept {
    return {0, 0, 0, alpha};
}

constexpr SDL_Color color_white(Uint8 alpha) noexcept {
    return {255, 255, 255, alpha};
}
}

#endif
```

drawing.cpp:

```
#include "drawing.h"
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

namespace Sdl {
// TODO fix passing unique pointer references around,
// start passing actual references to the required resources
void show_message(const Message_content& content, Message_box_type type) {
    check_function(SDL_ShowSimpleMessageBox(static_cast<Uint32>(type),
                                            content.title.c_str(),
                                            content.text.c_str(), nullptr));
}

SDL_Rect make_rect(Sdl::Point upper_left, Sdl::Point lower_right) noexcept {
    return {upper_left.x, upper_left.y, lower_right.x - upper_left.x,
            lower_right.y - upper_left.y};
}

SDL_Rect make_rect(Sdl::Point upper_left, int w, int h) noexcept {
    return {upper_left.x, upper_left.y, w, h};
}

Canvas::Canvas(const Screen_properties& properties)
    : window{SDL_CreateWindow(properties.title.c_str(),
                              properties.position.x,
                              properties.position.y,
                              properties.width,
                              properties.height,
                              SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN)},
      renderer{SDL_CreateRenderer(window.get(), -1, 0)} {
    check_pointer(window);
    check_pointer(renderer);
}

Line::Line(Point new_from, Angle_rad rads, int length) noexcept
    : from{new_from},
      to{static_cast<int>(std::sin(rads.value) * length + from.x),
         static_cast<int>(std::cos(rads.value) * length + from.y)}
// Sdl::Point_vector are integers in the SDL library, so narrowing
{  // has to happen
}

Line::Line(Point new_from, Point new_to) noexcept : from{new_from},
                                                    to{new_to} {}

void Texture_factory::add(const std::string& name, Unique_renderer& renderer) {
    Drawable_texture drawable = {load_texture(name.c_str(), renderer)};

    check_function(SDL_QueryTexture(drawable.texture.get(), nullptr, nullptr,
                                    &drawable.width, &drawable.height));

    m_map[name] = std::move(drawable);
}

bool Texture_factory::exists(const std::string& name) const noexcept {
    return m_map.count(name) != 0;
}

Drawable_texture Texture_factory::get(const std::string& name) const noexcept {
    return m_map.at(name);
}

Screen::Screen(const Screen_properties& properties) : m_canvas{properties} {
    check_function(SDL_SetRenderDrawBlendMode(m_canvas.renderer.get(),
                                              SDL_BLENDMODE_BLEND));
}

void Screen::add_draw(const std::string& name, Point where) {
    if (!m_factory.exists(name))
        m_factory.add(name, m_canvas.renderer);

    m_snapshots.push_back([this, name, where] {
        auto drawable = m_factory.get(name);

        SDL_Rect src{};
        SDL_Rect dst{};

        src.w = dst.w = drawable.width;
        src.h = dst.h = drawable.height;

        dst.x = where.x;
        dst.y = where.y;

        check_function(SDL_RenderCopy(m_canvas.renderer.get(),
                                      drawable.texture.get(), &src, &dst));
    });
}

void Screen::add_draw(Line line, SDL_Color color) {
    m_snapshots.push_back([this, line, color] {
        set_renderer_color(color);

        check_function(SDL_RenderDrawLine(m_canvas.renderer.get(), line.from.x,
                                          line.from.y, line.to.x, line.to.y));
    });
}

void Screen::add_draw(SDL_Rect rect, SDL_Color color, Color_filling filling) {
    m_snapshots.push_back([this, rect, color, filling] {
        set_renderer_color(color);

        check_function(SDL_RenderDrawRect(m_canvas.renderer.get(), &rect));

        // do check_function
        if (filling == Color_filling::Filled) {
            SDL_RenderFillRect(m_canvas.renderer.get(), &rect);
        }
    });
}

void Screen::redraw(SDL_Color color) {
    set_renderer_color(color);
    check_function(SDL_RenderClear(m_canvas.renderer.get()));

    for (const auto& snapshot : m_snapshots)
        snapshot();

    SDL_RenderPresent(m_canvas.renderer.get());
    m_snapshots.clear();
}

void Screen::set_renderer_color(SDL_Color color) {
    check_function(SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(m_canvas.renderer.get(), color.r,
                                          color.g, color.b, color.a));
}
}
```

flow.h:

```
#ifndef _SDLPP__FLOW__HEADER__
#define _SDLPP__FLOW__HEADER__

#include "drawing.h"
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

namespace Sdl {
bool key_down(SDL_Scancode);

class Basic_loop {
   public:
    using Function = std::function<void(void)>;

    explicit Basic_loop(Function) noexcept;
    void start();

   private:
    Function m_f{};
};

enum class Event_result : bool { Quit, Continue };

// Maybe add a Pump_event_loop class?

class Event_loop {
   public:
    using Event_function = std::function<Event_result(const SDL_Event&)>;
    using Unconditional_function = std::function<void(void)>;

    Event_loop(Event_function, Unconditional_function) noexcept;
    void start();

   private:
    Event_function m_event_f{};
    Unconditional_function m_unconditional_f{};
    SDL_Event m_event{};
};

class Thread_manager {
   public:
    using Quit_flag = std::atomic<bool>;
    using Thread_function = std::function<void()>;
    using Graphics_init_function = std::function<Screen()>;
    using Graphics_thread_function = std::function<void(Screen&)>;

    void add_graphics_thread(Graphics_init_function,
                             Graphics_thread_function f);
    void add_thread(Thread_function f);
    void start_all();

   private:
    Quit_flag quit_{false};
    std::vector<std::thread> threads_{};
};

// These loops can share a common concept in c++17

// TODO maybe an option to change the timers delay?
class Timer {
   public:
    explicit Timer(std::chrono::milliseconds) noexcept;
    /*
     * The user is expected to give a sane value, larger than 0,
     * not overflowing Uint32. Because small values are pretty much expected,
     * none of this is actually checked, so beware or check it yourself.
     */

    bool ready() noexcept;

    std::chrono::milliseconds get_delay() const noexcept;
    void set_delay(std::chrono::milliseconds) noexcept;

   private:
    Uint32 delay_{};
    Uint32 current_{SDL_GetTicks()};
};
}

#endif
```

flow.cpp:

```
#include "flow.h"
#include "SDL2/SDL.h"

namespace Sdl {
bool key_down(SDL_Scancode scancode) {
    return SDL_GetKeyboardState(nullptr)[scancode];
}

Basic_loop::Basic_loop(Function f) noexcept : m_f{f} {}

void Basic_loop::start() {
    while (!SDL_QuitRequested()) {
        m_f();
    }
}

Event_loop::Event_loop(Event_function event_f,
                       Unconditional_function unconditional_f) noexcept
    : m_event_f{event_f},
      m_unconditional_f{unconditional_f} {}

void Event_loop::start() {
    while (true) {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&m_event)) {
            if (m_event_f(m_event) == Event_result::Quit)
                return;  // Quit if the user says so
        }

        m_unconditional_f();
    }
}

void Thread_manager::add_graphics_thread(Graphics_init_function init,
                                         Graphics_thread_function f) {
    threads_.push_back(std::thread{[this, init, f] {
        auto screen = init();

        while (!quit_) {
            SDL_PumpEvents();
            f(screen);
            if (SDL_QuitRequested()) {
                quit_ = true;
            }
        }
    }});
}

void Thread_manager::add_thread(Thread_function f) {
    threads_.push_back(std::thread{[f, this] {
        while (!quit_) {
            f();
        }
    }});
}

void Thread_manager::start_all() {
    for (auto& thread : threads_) {
        thread.join();
    }
}

Timer::Timer(std::chrono::milliseconds delay) noexcept {
    set_delay(delay);
}

bool Timer::ready() noexcept {
    auto ticks = SDL_GetTicks();

    if (ticks >= delay_ + current_) {
        current_ = ticks;
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

std::chrono::milliseconds Timer::get_delay() const noexcept {
    return std::chrono::milliseconds{delay_};
}

void Timer::set_delay(std::chrono::milliseconds delay) noexcept {
    delay_ = static_cast<Uint32>(delay.count());
}
}
```

Comment: I would have seporated the SDL wrapper and the game into separate code reviews.

Comment: You should read: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/228783/14065)

Comment: @LokiAstari As far as I can see, the link posted doesn't seem to say anything bad about trailing underscores (and if it did, it would be a preference, not a standard constraint)

Comment: Leading underscore followed by an uppercase letter and double underscore. `_GAME_LOGIC_H__`. All these identifiers are reserved for use by the implementation. As such using them is UB.

Comment: Oh Jesus! I was doing that and not even realizing... that's scary. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: You are using boost for optional but c++17 provides that: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional

Comment: @AntonioCS Thanks for the info, but check the tags - the code is written for c++14.

Comment: @EnnMichael Right, missed that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh wow, that's some really nice C++ code :)

Here are some few things you could do/or not, depends:

- Lambdas can deduce their return type, so the `-> void` is unnecessary:

  ```
  Util::for_each(table.blocks(),
                 [point, &found](auto pos, const auto& oc) /*-> void*/ {
                     if (found || !oc)
                         return;

                     if (pos == point)
                         found = true;
                 });
  ```
- Don't recreate `std::uniform_int_distribution` every time you need a random number, instead, just like `std::random_device`, create it once and use it multiple times. Quick fix: make it static :)
- You're not consistent with function declarations in your class definitions:

  ```
  Event_loop(Event_function, Unconditional_function) noexcept; // no names
  void add_graphics_thread(Graphics_init_function,
                       Graphics_thread_function f); // name!!
  ```

  Some of them have names, some don't and some have both.
- Personally, I think those `*_deleter` functors are unnecessary, but the library is not as flexible without them, so you choose.
- You can abbreviate `std::function<void(void)>` to `std::function<void()>`
- Remove TODOs when you are done with them:

  ```
  // TODO Maybe this shouldn't be a template...
  ```

  `Point` is not a template...
- You might like aggregate initialization without arguments, but this is only necessary for built-ins, classes without user defined constructor, ... (like `Point`) ([more info](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization)). `std::string title{};` can be safely replaced with `std::string title;`
- Operators can be implemented in terms of other operators, which is better (less code -> maintenance) and shorter to write:

  ```
  constexpr bool operator!=(Point lhs, Point rhs) noexcept {
      // return lhs.x != rhs.x && lhs.y != rhs.y;
      return !(lhs == rhs);
  }
  ```

  Same with the other operators.
- You are using a lot of capturing lambdas in your code, which are saved using a `std::function`. This is not ideal, as usage of `std::function` not only slows down the program, but also the compilation time due to type-erase. [See this for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5057382/what-is-the-performance-overhead-of-stdfunction). There isn't really an alternative though, so maybe use it sparingly?
- [`std::mt19937`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine) is faster than calls to `std::random_device`, so consider using that instead.
- Destructors are implicitly `noexcept`, so you don't need to specify it explicitly: `~Sdl_system_control() /*noexcept*/;`

Comment: Thank you very very much :-). I would just like to mention how good advice "Operators can be implemented in terms of other operators, which is better" is, because yesterday I found that the implementation `return lhs.x != rhs.x && lhs.y != rhs.y;` actually has a bug - it uses `&&`, but it should use `||` instead - and this would have been avoided if I just implemented it in terms of `operator==` like you said.